# Button escapes stacklayout on lower resolution

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

Here is a screenshot of the problem (Left= Xamarin.Forms previewer; Right= ADV 768x1080)

[image]

Code:

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="#292929" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20,0,20,0" CornerRadius="4" Padding="0">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5">
                 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Tomato">
                    <Label FontSize="Small" Text="ABBONAMENTO 30 giorni" TextColor="White"/>
                    <Label FontSize="Small" Text="€10,99" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="#ff9900"/>
                 </StackLayout>
                    <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="ISCRIVITI" TextColor="#eeeeee" BackgroundColor="#FF9900" CornerRadius="4"/>
        </StackLayout>
 </Frame>
```

The frames are put in a `StackLayout`, which parent is a Grid.

The problem persists on low resolution devices only.
Can you tell me why is this happening, and how to fix it?

I need this layout to be height-aware and responsive.

Comment: It clearly says there is no room for your controls to render in lower resolution. Need to see all of your containers (any explicit height/width is set) to exactly tell where the problem is.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @dhilmathy there is no explicit height/width. The frames (3 frames) are put in a `StackLayout`, which parent is a Grid built of 3 rows, one for logo, one for some text, and one for the stacklayout containing the frames. The proportion of the rows is .25*, .25* and .50* for the frames